# Random password generation with digit, letter, symbol

Tags: python

I want to generate a random password.

It should be made up of symbol, letter, and digit such as:

tqpV4aJ

I!WZuYvBv7

S@OPToyu0u

a) Contains 6-10 characters

b) Contains exactly 1 symbol from the set {!,@,#,-,@,+,%}.

c) Contains exactly 1 digit, i.e., any of the numbers 0-9 except for the number 5, which is excluded.

d) Contains upper or lower case letters among the remaining characters, except for ’e’ and ’E’, which are excluded

e) The positions of the characters are chosen randomly.

How can I achieve this in a pythonic way?

---

my attempt (fail: can only output one letter):

```
import random
import string

symbol=('!','@','#','-','@','+','%')
x= random.choice(symbol)

digit= random.randint(0,9)
if digit!=5:
    y= digit

letter= random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
if letter!= 'e' or 'E':
    z= letter

def main():    
  list= x + str(y) + z
  size= random.randint(6, 10)
  pw=''.join(random.choice(list) for i in range(size))
  print pw

main()
```

Comment: `print pw` are you using Python 2 for this? Do you have to use 2? Please upgrade to 3 if you can.

Comment: yes, need to use python2

Comment: (1) Create string of all ascii letters, remove e and E from it. (2) Create string of 4-8 letters chosen randomly from first string. (3) Chose symbol and position where to insert in password string. Insert it. (4) Same for digit.

Comment: if you need 5 letters then you have to use `for`-loop to repeat choice 5 times (and uppend to `z`). OR create string with all chars except e/E and use `random.shuffle(letters)` to randomly change lettter's positions and then get `letters[:5]`

Comment: BTW: it is wrong `if letter!= 'e' or 'E`  - it has to be `if letter != 'e' and letter != 'E` or `if letter not in ('e', 'E'):`

Comment: or use `string.ascii_letters = string.ascii_letters.replace('e', '').replace('E', '')`

Answer (score 2):

All the answers written here should use the [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/secrets.html) rather than the `random` module to generate secret values, including passwords.  In particular:

- `random.randint(0, n)` should be replaced with `secrets.randbelow(n+1)`.
- `random.choice(x)` should be replaced with `secrets.choice(x)`.
- `random.choices(...)` should be replaced with `secrets.SystemRandom().choices(...)` or `random.SystemRandom().choices(...)`.
- `random.shuffle(...)` should be replaced with `secrets.SystemRandom().shuffle(...)` or `random.SystemRandom().shuffle(...)`.

The functions in the `random` module (including `random.randint`, `random.choice`, `random.choices`, `random.sample`, and `random.shuffle`) use a global random number generator that's not necessarily designed for information security, so using those functions can make passwords easier to guess than they already are -- especially in view of the maximum length requirement and restricted character distribution you give in your question.  In general, whenever `random.*` functions are called to generate passwords, they should be replaced by `secrets.SystemRandom().*` instead (or a suitable method in the `secrets` module).

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly clear from the comments. Basic idea is:

- build up lists to choose from
- make choices
- join into a single list
- shuffle the list
- join back to a single string

It should be noted this is not secure, and should not be used to actually generate passwords.

```py
import random
import string

# it's nice to have your constants up top and in CAPS
SYMBOLS = ('!', '@', '#', '-', '@', '+', '%')
# it's easy to just omit '5' from a list of numbers
# easier to just have the list already be strings than mess around with ints
NUMBERS = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9')
# quick list comprehension to omit 'e' and 'E'
LETTERS = [char for char in string.ascii_letters if char != 'e' and char != 'E']

# put all our logic in a function
def create_password_insecure():
    # pick a symbol
    chosen_symbol = random.choice(SYMBOLS)
    # pick a number
    chosen_number = random.choice(NUMBERS)
    # pick some letters to fill out our 6-10 chars
    # we pick 4-8 not 6-10, since 2 chars will be symbol/number
    number_of_letters = random.randint(4, 8)
    # quick list comprehension to pick our letters
    chosen_letters = [random.choice(LETTERS) for i in range(number_of_letters)]
    # get all our elements in a single list
    password_elements_list = [chosen_symbol] + [chosen_number] + chosen_letters
    # (pseudo)randomize the list
    random.shuffle(password_elements_list)

    pseudorandom_password = ''.join(password_elements_list)
    print (pseudorandom_password)

create_password_insecure()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach can be simplified with more listcomps and careful character replacing:

```
import random
import string

def get_password():
    pass_ = [random.choice(list(set(string.ascii_letters) - {"e", "E"})) for i in range(random.randint(6, 10))]  # Initial password contains random letters, excluding e and E
    index_1 = random.randint(0, len(pass_) - 1)
    pass_[index_1] = random.choice(["!", "@", "#", "-", "@", "+", "%"])  # Replace a random character with a symbol
    index_2 = index_1  # Initialize index_2 as equal to index_1 so that it will be randomized at least once

    while index_1 == index_2:  # Ensure the two indexes are not equal
        index_2 = random.randint(0, len(pass_) - 1)

    pass_[index_2] = str(random.choice([random.randint(0, 4), random.randint(6, 9)]))  # Replace the chosen random character with a random digit, excluding 5

    return "".join(pass_)

print(get_password())
```

Comment: Your answer should use `secrets` rather than `random`; see my answer.

Comment: He asked for a random password, not a cryptographically secure one. From the viewpoint of someone trying to crack a password, the difference between a pseudorandom one and one generated by `secrets` is negligible, especially if the attacker doesn't know it was generated. Without the context where he was planning to use this, I can't really modify my answer to reflect that. I based mine on the assumption that he was already using the `random` library for a reason and only needed clarification on how to process its output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
import random, string

symbols = '!@#-@+%'   #choose 1
digits  = '123467890' #choose 1
letters = set(string.ascii_letters)-set('eE') #choose 4 to 8

chars   = random.sample(letters,random.randint(4,8))
chars.append(random.choice(symbols))
chars.append(random.choice(digits))
random.shuffle(chars)

pwd = ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: Your answer should use `secrets` rather than `random`; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: upgrade to Python 3, step 2:

```py
import secrets
import string

letter_choices = string.ascii_letters.replace("e", "").replace("E", "")
num_letters = secrets.choice(range(4, 9))  # between 4 and 8 letters
password = [secrets.choice(letter_choices) for _ in range(num_letters)]

symbol = secrets.choice("!@#-+%")
password.insert(secrets.randbelow(len(password) + 1), symbol)

digit = secrets.choice("012346789")  # 5 is excluded
password.insert(secrets.randbelow(len(password) + 1), digit)

print(''.join(password))
```