# Cannot generate random password with string module in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, random

```
def generatePass():
    global Symbol
    if Symbol:
        pass_len = entry.get()
        temp = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        password = random.sample(temp,pass_len)
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, password)
        print(password)
    else:
        pass_len = entry.get()
        temp = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        password = random.sample(temp,pass_len)
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, password)
        print(password)
```

When I run this code it said **TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**. The error is given from `password = random.sample(temp,pass_len)` I tried fixing this error by add `int()` before `random.sample(temp,pass_len)` but it didn't work. Any solution?

Comment: Which line is giving this error ?

Comment: password = random.sample(temp,pass_len) is giving an error. Do you need the entire code? Sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: What is the type of temp ?

Comment: you can check its type with : `print(type(temp))`

Comment: it's string ('str')

Comment: Does doing `random.sample(temp, k=pass_len)` solve the issue? Also what is in `entry`, because `pass_len` is supposed to be an integer, yes?

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue. `entry` is an entry i created to get user in put for `pass_len` and `pass_len` is an integer

Comment: Thank you guys! I have solved the issue. I searched for `random.sample` on google an found that `random.sample(sequence,k)` and k must be an integer. So I used `random.sample(temp, int(pass_len))` and it does the work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random password generation with digit, letter, symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61399901/random-password-generation-with-digit-letter-symbol)